# What is a term for someone who doesn't know what to do with their life?

Tags: meaning, expressions, synonyms

Is there a term for a person who doesn't know what to do in their life?
Is there an expression also?

For example, a person who completed a degree, and now he's not sure he wants to work at the field he studied at the university, maybe he wants to do a long trip and find himself...

Another example: A person who doesn't know what to study, and is just trying many things until he finds something that he feels he wants to do in his life.

Thank you.

Comment: Some people would call it "drifting" as in 'floating aimlessly on the tide', etc but many such people have later found their purpose in life.

Comment: [Indecisive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indecisive)?

Comment: But as "a term for a person," @EnglishStudent, that would give us *drifter,* which does not really hit the mark.

Comment: @Brian Donovan very true. I am not putting forward 'drifter' as a description for the person, but recommend only the adjective 'drifting.' The noun 'drifter' seems often to have a negative or even pejorative meaning.

Comment: I would offer, as less derogatory than most of what seems forthcoming here, *seeker, explorer,* or *undecided.* The first two have quite positive connotations, though those can be reversed by scare quotes or other signs of sarcasm. *(Seeker* used by itself, with no specifying of what is sought, seems current to me, with rather spiritual overtones, but I am not readily finding support in dictionaries.) *Undecided* is often used as a (count) noun for an undergraduate student who has not yet selected a major; some people, admittedly, sneer at such students, but plenty of us do not in the least.

Comment: *Undecided* as suggested by @Brian Donovan would be the most accurate and value-neutral term to suit your case.

Answer (score 1):

Drifting.

Some people would call it [drifting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drifting) as in 'floating aimlessly on the tide', etc.

Example of usage:

> My son is 27 and I am worried about him. He is highly intelligent but since dropping out of university he has not had any settled periods of employment and appears to be ***drifting*** with no real sense of what to do with his life.
>   (I have emphasised the word referred to in this answer.)

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2015/jun/12/my-son-is-drifting-through-life

However, in the experience of not only myself (regarding people I know) but also history, many such people have later found their purpose in life.

Answer (score -5):

The person is

**clueless**

> Having no knowledge, understanding, or ability.

(Oxford)

The word is applied to such people as depicted in your examples. The person has no "no knowledge, understanding, or ability" to direct his own life or come up with a plan for his life.

Although neither the  dictionary nor real life examples indicate that this word is necessarily derogatory, it certainly fits the scenarios you've given.

You can also say that he

**doesn't have a clue**

as to what to do (with his life). This means he *has no idea* (OED).

Comment: I disagree - clueless seems pejorative of the said person.  They might be a perfectly intelligent person who hasn't yet decided a career path, for example.  Neither intelligence, understanding nor ability are measures of  decisiveness.

Comment: This answer seems rather to express contempt for such persons (which they may well not deserve) than to offer an adequately specific term for them, one that English speakers would naturally and consistently interpret as implying the specific characteristics OP mentions.

Comment: @marcel et al.  neither the dictionary nor real life examples indicate that the word is necessarily pejorative. Additionally, while not asking for a neutral term,  the OP offers two scenarios in which the word is highly appropriate.

Comment: In defense of the word option provided by @Clare, 'clueless' simply means 'having no idea' and OP did give the description "a person that don't know what to do in his life" which could itself possibly  be interpreted to carry a less-than-positive value judgment.

Comment: Sorry, not having a go, it's just my opinion :) A quick search of `clueless negative` showed up some fairly scathing news articles! Admittedly the OP isn't overly clear as to the context...